# How to unify or integrate search bar in folium for multiple layers?

Tags: python, folium, search, leaflet-plugins

How to integrate multiple layers with one search bar using `folium` python?

Data:

```
import geopandas


states = geopandas.read_file(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PublicaMundi/MappingAPI/master/data/geojson/us-states.json",
    driver="GeoJSON",
)

cities = geopandas.read_file(
    "https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_populated_places_simple.geojson",
    driver="GeoJSON",
)

states_sorted = states.sort_values(by="density", ascending=False)

states_sorted.head(5).append(states_sorted.tail(5))[["name", "density"]]

def rd2(x):
    return round(x, 2)


minimum, maximum = states["density"].quantile([0.05, 0.95]).apply(rd2)

mean = round(states["density"].mean(), 2)


import branca


colormap = branca.colormap.LinearColormap(
    colors=["#f2f0f7", "#cbc9e2", "#9e9ac8", "#756bb1", "#54278f"],
    index=states["density"].quantile([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]),
    vmin=minimum,
    vmax=maximum,
)

colormap.caption = "Population Density in the United States"

us_cities = geopandas.sjoin(cities, states, how="inner", predicate="within")

pop_ranked_cities = us_cities.sort_values(by="pop_max", ascending=False)[
    ["nameascii", "pop_max", "geometry"]
].iloc[:20]
```

**Folium Map:**

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import Search


m = folium.Map(location=[38, -97], zoom_start=4)


def style_function(x):
    return {
        "fillColor": colormap(x["properties"]["density"]),
        "color": "black",
        "weight": 2,
        "fillOpacity": 0.5,
    }


stategeo = folium.GeoJson(
    states,
    name="US States",
    style_function=style_function,
    tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=["name", "density"], aliases=["State", "Density"], localize=True
    ),
).add_to(m)

citygeo = folium.GeoJson(
    pop_ranked_cities,
    name="US Cities",
    tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=["nameascii", "pop_max"], aliases=["", "Population Max"], localize=True
    ),
).add_to(m)

statesearch = Search(
    layer=stategeo,
    geom_type="Polygon",
    placeholder="Search for a US State",
    collapsed=False,
    search_label="name",
    weight=3,
).add_to(m)

citysearch = Search(
    layer=citygeo,
    geom_type="Point",
    placeholder="Search for a US City",
    collapsed=True,
    search_label="nameascii",
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
colormap.add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

How to have one search bar to search US State/City??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved a similar problem myself.
Modified your code, should work

**Folium Map:**

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import Search


m = folium.Map(location=[38, -97], zoom_start=4)


def style_function(x):
    return {
        "fillColor": colormap(x["properties"]["density"]),
        "color": "black",
        "weight": 2,
        "fillOpacity": 0.5,
    }

# create a group to combine other groups to be searched for.
search_group = folium.FeatureGroup(
    control=False
).add_to(m)

stategeo = folium.GeoJson(
    states,
    name="US States",
    style_function=style_function,
    tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=["name", "density"], aliases=["State", "Density"], localize=True
    ),
).add_to(m).add_to(search_group) # add to `m` and `search_group`

citygeo = folium.GeoJson(
    pop_ranked_cities,
    name="US Cities",
    tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=["nameascii", "pop_max"], aliases=["", "Population Max"], localize=True
    ),
).add_to(m).add_to(search_group) # add to `m` and `search_group`

statesearch = Search(
    layer=search_group,  # search by elements from search_group
    geom_type="Polygon",
    placeholder="Search for a US State",
    collapsed=False,
    search_label="name",
    weight=3,
).add_to(m)


folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
colormap.add_to(m)

m
```

Comment: it's working only for state search, I'm not able to search any cities

Comment: @Ceraunophile you have to change 'nameascii' key in pop_ranked_cities dict to ''name' or add 'name' key instead changing